# the jsp cannot get the request scope value

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp

here is the code,in the controller class,i can get the "list" data,
but in the jsp,i can't get it.i just want get the request scope,but 
when i use alert the list,it was null,how can i do?

```js
    function getTableData(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            async : true,
            url : "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/echarts/pageContent.json",
            data : {'IF_BIZNAME':$("#interName  option:selected").text(),'APPLICATION_KEY':$("#channel").val(),"pageNo":$("#pageNo").val()},
            success : function(result) {

                }
            })
    }
```

```js
   <c:forEach var="echartsTable" items="${tableList}">
        <tr>
            <td>${echartsTable.t }</td>
            <td>${echartsTable.ywl }</td>
            <td>${echartsTable.sbl }</td>
            <td>${echartsTable.sbv }</td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">详情</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

```html
    @RequestMapping("/pageContent.json")
    public void getPageContent(String APPLICATION_KEY, String IF_BIZNAME,
                               @RequestParam(value = "pageNo", defaultValue = "1")String pageNo, HttpServletRequest request){
        List<EchartsTable> echartsTables = interfaceFailInfoService
                .selectPageContent(IF_BIZNAME, APPLICATION_KEY, Integer.parseInt(pageNo));
        request.setAttribute("tableList",echartsTables);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Z7k.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a mess! You did everything wrong that you could do wrong.

1. Ajax requests xml but you need html.
2. Ajax requests xml but becomes json.

Do not use `.ajax(`, use `.load` instead and give the surrounding table of `c:forEach` an id like "abc123".

Then use this function instead:

```
function getTableData(){
   $.post("path",{..:xx}, function(){
       $.load(' #abc123');
       //        ^ the space is important!
   });
}
```

This means you do not need the `getPageContent`-method.

Comment: thanks,but i just want to request the path and put the data into the request Scope ,and i don't want to reponse anything so i write like that,and i edit my code like this                                                              function getTableData(){
$.post("path",{..:xx})                                                                                                              $.reload(' #abc123');
    //        ^ the space is important!
}     but it can't works

Comment: $.reload() is not a function?,the firebug says

Comment: I meant load, not reload

Comment: $.load is not a function too,but i can get the response data see the pic

Comment: @jiashu.L I've rejected your edit. Please don't edit the answer - update your question if necessary